# std::get_time - How to check for parsing error

Tags: c++, windows

I am using the following code to parse a stringstream into tm struct:

```
std::tm tm;
std::stringstream ss("Jan 9 2014 12:35:34");
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
```

I am interested to check whether parsing error has occured (invalid input).
It seems that this function does not throws an exception.
did not find usefull information in the documentation:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Sounds like checking the 'goodbit' may be the direction, but I am not sure how to do it.

(I am using VS2013 compiler)

Comment: I tried reading the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get/get_time but my eyes started to bleed due to template hell.

Comment: @wcochran, You're not alone :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As always, `std::istream` reports error by setting one of its [`iostate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate), which can be tested using the member function [`fail()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail), [`operator!`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!), or by [converting the stream object to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). If you want to config the stream object so that it throws an exception when an error occurs, you can call [`exceptions()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Here's a small example that uses the member function `fail()` to check if an error has occurred.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::tm t;
    std::istringstream ss("2011-Februar-18 23:12:34");
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S");
    if (ss.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Parsing "2011-Februar-18" using "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S" will succeed and results in 00:00:00. Be aware of this...

Answer (score 5):

Using `std::get_time()` with an `std::istream` set the state flags in case the `std::time_get<...>::get_time()` fails. That is, you'd just use

```
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
if (!ss) {
    // deal with an error
}
```